# Filter using Index counting entries in specific cells

Tags: google-sheets, indexing

I'm using the following formula to filter all same results from column B and to sum the values in Column's O and P where rows match the Column B value

```
=INDEX(IFNA(QUERY(QUERY({B:B, O:P*1}, "select Col1,count(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), "offset 1", )),"")
```

It currently does (almost) all I want but also in the above is a column which counts where there are entries in Column B but I actually want this count to be done for Column O instead of B.

Can anyone assist in getting the formula updated to count actual entries in Column P instead of Column B?

Comment: Can you clarify the last part as they do have the same thought but different in result you are looking to get, it could be a typo. If you can also provide a minimum reproducible sample that shows expected results and what it was currently doing that you want to alter for better grasp of your question?
Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Babanana - I have produced a very small sample of the spreadsheet in question and it is available at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gAzB-8SX1RnVG26SxgQ5GF2058swl4bQFSq8wSBHjQo/edit?usp=sharing

The sheet in question is "Date Filter" and the column with incorrect value is AT1 which reads 17 at the moment as it is currently counting all cells in Column A with a value in it but I want it to count all cells from any of columns F, G, L, M, O, P (just one of these not all).

Hope this makes it a bit clearer as I appreciate my original post wasn't great

Comment: Thank you for providing a sample sheet, can you try to clarify your expected result with the given columns, What will it look like, this part brings a little bit of confusion with me.  I want it to count all cells from any of the columns F, G, L, M, O, P (just one of these not all). From what it looks like you are looking to read through the row of the columns given and if a column value is not empty then that will be counted as one then go to the next row. Am I getting it correctly?

Comment: So the expected result in column AT1 is 10 not 17 as it should only count rows which have values in Column E but presently it is counting Column A. I unnecessarily overcomplicated my previous post with all of those different columns when you can just focus on column E. So basically if there is a value in Column E, I want that cell to be counted in column AT1 - hope this makes more sense but if not let me know and I will explain what the sheet is actually designed to do to try and assist more :)

Comment: In your `Date Filter` sheet Column_E has data in all the cells from E1:E17 just like the Column_B the current formula is referring to in `Cell_AS1` (https://i.imgur.com/4dwPyLh.png)

Comment: Apologies both, it is Column F I was supposed to refer to not Column E (I was sat in the wrong sheet when I was posting that message earlier - I was at work when I sent the message so wasn't concentrating).

So basically, Column AT1 needs to count all cells from Column F which have a value in them

Comment: Based on your comment you can come up with an easier solution like this one as for your case: `=COUNTA(F1:F)` This might be the best formula you can use it is directly connected to it, I am thinking that you might have a different thing to worry about since you are using a more complex formula, if the formula helps you please let me know so I can post this as an answer if not please do share thing you factoring about so we can adjust the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight change to your existing formula; you may try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(QUERY(QUERY({B:B, O:P*1,F:F}, "select Col1,count(Col4),sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col4 is not null group by Col1"), "offset 1", )),"")
```